# How do I search for '%stars%' within a Postgresql array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am trying to find a record in a Postgresql Query, where I have a column 'alternate_names'

```
t.text     "alternate_names",          default: [],                 array: true
```

And, I would like to find the following record:

```
altenate_names = ['All Stars']
```

where my criteria is 'Stars'

In other words, how can I write the following

```
select * from group where '%Stars%' = ANY(alternate_names);
```

But this won't return my record above because it has the array ['All Stars']...so, how can I perform an ILIKE '%stars%' with an array?

Comment: `select * from group where alternate_names::text like '%Stars%';` if you want `LIKE` opertor. not sure if it is effective though, but wildcard before pattern won't be effective in any query probably

Comment: @VaoTsun I used your answer and it works great. Feel free to submit as an answer and i'll mark it off. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want LIKE operator:

```
select * from group where alternate_names::text like '%Stars%';
```

Comparing text representation of array against pattern is not effective, but wildcard before pattern won't be effective in any query on `text[]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unnest` to check for partial match of all elements in an array.
Ex:

```
select * from group where exists (select 1 from unnest(alternate_names) as a_names where a_names like '%Stars%');
```

Comment: please comment when down-voting